# Convert Japan Administrative Boundary Data to Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, gdal, convert, administrative-boundaries

I've downloaded [Administrative Boundary data from the Japan MLIT (Ministry of Land, Infrastructure and Transport)](http://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj-e/jpgis/datalist/KsjTmplt-N03.html), but it is in an XML based format referred to as JPGIS or KSJ.

Are there any scripts, GDAL plugins, etc available for converting this format to a Shapefile or GeoJSON?

Comment: online XML to SHP http://converter.mygeodata.eu/ limited to 20mb file size (unless donate)

Comment: Looks like the Japan MLIT provides data [in Shapefile format as well.](http://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj-e/gml/gml_datalist.html)

There may still be some data that is only available in the JPGIS format, so tools for converting formats would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tool that can convert JPGIS data which are in xml format into shapefile data. The tool is named [ksjtool](http://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj/jpgis/jpgis_tool.html), and you can choose between (1) 32Bit or (2) 64Bit, as you can see from the image below:
[image]

After downloading the file, unzip ksjtool, and install it. Then, open the ksjtool, and you will have two inputs, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

(1) Input the xml file;

(2) Input the name of the directory in which the output shapefile will be written;

Then you will have two buttons at the lower right corner:

(3) The upper button is to "Execute the conversion", and

(4) The lower button is to "Close the tool".

I hope this can help.